# Fetch API headers are not correctly received after GET request

Tags: javascript, python, django, http-headers, fetch-api

I am using the Fetch API to download a file and the code to do that looks as follows:

```js
  const response = fetch(`{% url 'export_xls' %}?${urlParams}`,{
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}',
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let file = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.location.assign(file);
    })
```

This does result in a downloaded file, however, the name of the file is randomized, instead of using the filename given in the `Content-Disposition` header. The headers, which I could see in the chrome dev tools are only the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type`, however, when I console log the headers of the response, the `Content-Disposition` header is there.

The django view, which is being called with the fetch API sets the header, so I do not understand why the filename is not correct:

```py
    response = FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="foo.xlsx")
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.xlsx'
    response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Content-Disposition'  # I read it could be a CORS problem and this could solve it, however, no luck

    return response
```

After some googling, I found multiple threads where people recommend using an `a` tag element and setting the `download` attribute, however, as the `Content-Disposition` header is set correctly, I would expect to have the file with the proper filename, without doing any additional work in the JS code.

Comment: the `blob` doesn't "know" anything about the content-disposition header - *without doing any additional work* - unfortunately, you will have to do additional work

Comment: Also, `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.xlsx'` should be `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.xlsx"'`. Missing closing double quote.

Comment: Yes, the closing quotation was missing, but sadly that did not solve the problem. @Bravo could you please explain why the blob does not know about the header and maybe how could I then set the file name?

Comment: the blob is data, it has no knowledge from whence it came

Comment: I still do not understand how the type of the blob is then correctly set. When I change the `Content-Type` header to something else and console.log the blob, I can see that the type of the blob also changes respectively.

Comment: of course a blob knows what it is, it doesn't know what it is called